# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
const Category = (categories) => {
  return (
    <div className="shop-by-category">
      <div className="categories">
        {categories.data.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id} className="category">
            <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_APP_DEV_URL + item.attributes.img.data.attributes.url} alt="" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );  
};
```

And here is the error I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

I've checked out every possible thing, but still not working.

Comment: Is `Category` supposed to be a React component? If so then the standard convention is to name the props object `props` ***or*** to destructure the passed `data` prop from the props object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is simply telling you that the attribute 'data' does not exist on 'categories'. If you're fetching the categories from some external APIs , this is mostly because the database is still empty, so there are no categories yet. However, if you still want to render your component, you can easily check the attributes by adding a '?'  if you're not sure if they exist or not.

```
 const Category = (categories) => {
  return categories?.data?.map((item) => (
    <img
      src={
        process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_APP_DEV_URL +
        item.attributes.img.data.attributes.url
      }
      alt=""
    />
  ));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `categories` object you're passing to the component doesn't have a `data` field. You can add a guard clause to render the component:

```
const Category = (categories) => {
  if (!categories || !categories.data) {
    return <>No Data</>;
  }
  return categories.data.map((item) => (
    <img
      src={
        process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_APP_DEV_URL +
        item.attributes.img.data.attributes.url
      }
      alt=""
    />
  ));
};
```